# How to listen for device changes on a GLFW application?

Tags: c++, winapi, glfw

How exactly do I use this callback function to my glfw app?

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(
  HWND hwnd,       // handle to window
  UINT uMsg,       // WM_DEVICECHANGE
  WPARAM wParam,   // device-change event
  LPARAM lParam    // event-specific data
);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "device changes"? The WindowProc is a very low-level mechanism for processing messages sent to your Windows .. window. GLFW has its own message processing system that already implements / supplants WindowProc

Comment: @Botje I want to listen for any USB device being connected with WM_DEVICECHANGE. Where can I find the documentation for the equivalent with GLFW?

Comment: If you are interested in controllers being plugged in or out, then [`glfwSetJoystickCallback()`](https://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/input_guide.html#joystick_event) will have you covered.

Comment: Simply create a [message-only window](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/window-features#message-only-windows) that receives the `WM_DEVICECHANGE` messages.

Comment: The default [WindowProc provided by GLFW](https://github.com/glfw/glfw/blob/114776a24605418e6d719d2f30141e351e93c6e0/src/win32_window.c#L490-L1217) does not provide an extension point for you to use. You will have to follow @IInspectable's suggestion.

Comment: alright, i'll see about making a message only window. cheers